# Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, extjs

I try to apply the example Extjs 6 Google Maps but it appears an error google is not defined on GMapPanel.js file. Can anyone help me why this error displays, I mention that I've spent time to read here and on other forum why this error but nothing give me the answer? thanks in advance

viewMap.js

```js
Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        title: 'Google Map',
        layout: 'fit',
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        items: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                id: 'show-btn',
                text: 'Click here'
            }]
    });
    Ext.require([
        'Ext.window.*',
        'Ext.ux.GMapPanel'
    ]);
    var mapwin;
    Ext.get('show-btn').on('click', function () {
        // create the window on the first click and reuse on subsequent clicks
        if (mapwin) {
            mapwin.show();
        } else {
            mapwin = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
                autoShow: true,
                layout: 'fit',
                title: 'GMap Window',
                closeAction: 'hide',
                width: 450,
                height: 450,
                border: false,
                x: 40,
                y: 60,
                mapTypeId: 'google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP',
                mapConfOpts: ['enableScrollWheelZoom', 'enableDoubleClickZoom', 'enableDragging'],
                mapControls: ['GSmallMapControl', 'GMapTypeControl', 'NonExistantControl'],
                items: {
                    xtype: 'gmappanel',
                    center: {
                        geoCodeAddr: '4 Yawkey Way, Boston, MA, 02215-3409, USA',
                        marker: {title: 'Fenway Park'}
                    },
                    markers: [{
                            lat: 42.339641,
                            lng: -71.094224,
                            title: 'Boston Museum of Fine Arts',
                            listeners: {
                                click: function (e) {
                                    Ext.Msg.alert('It\'s fine', 'and it\'s art.');
                                }
                            }
                        }, {
                            lat: 42.339419,
                            lng: -71.09077,
                            title: 'Northeastern University'
                        }]
                }
            });

        }
    });
});
```

GMapPanel.js

```js
    Ext.define('Ext.ux.GMapPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    
    alias: 'widget.gmappanel',
    
    requires: ['Ext.window.MessageBox'],
    
    initComponent : function(){
        Ext.applyIf(this,{
            plain: true,
            gmapType: 'map',
            border: false
        });
        
        this.callParent();        
    },
    
    onBoxReady : function(){
        var center = this.center;
        this.callParent(arguments);       
        
        if (center) {
            if (center.geoCodeAddr) {
                this.lookupCode(center.geoCodeAddr, center.marker);
            } else {
                this.createMap(center);
            }
        } else {
            Ext.raise('center is required');
        }
              
    },
    
    createMap: function(center, marker) {
        var options = Ext.apply({}, this.mapOptions);
        
        options = Ext.applyIf(options, {
            zoom: 14,
            center: center,
            mapTypeId: 'google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID'
        });
        this.gmap = new google.maps.Map(this.body.dom, options);
        if (marker) {
            this.addMarker(Ext.applyIf(marker, {
                position: center
            }));
        }
        
        Ext.each(this.markers, this.addMarker, this);
        this.fireEvent('mapready', this, this.gmap);
    },
    
    addMarker: function(marker) {
        marker = Ext.apply({
            map: this.gmap
        }, marker);
        
        if (!marker.position) {
            marker.position = new google.maps.LatLng(marker.lat, marker.lng);
        }
        var o =  new google.maps.Marker(marker);
        Ext.Object.each(marker.listeners, function(name, fn){
            google.maps.event.addListener(o, name, fn);    
        });
        return o;
    },
    
    lookupCode : function(addr, marker) {
        this.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        this.geocoder.geocode({
            address: addr
        }, Ext.Function.bind(this.onLookupComplete, this, [marker], true));
    },
    
    onLookupComplete: function(data, response, marker){
        if (response != 'OK') {
            Ext.MessageBox.alert('Error', 'An error occured: "' + response + '"');
            return;
        }
        this.createMap(data[0].geometry.location, marker);
    },
    
    afterComponentLayout : function(w, h){
        this.callParent(arguments);
        this.redraw();
    },
    
    redraw: function(){
        var map = this.gmap;
        if (map) {
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        }
    }
 
});
```

Comment: Where/how are you including the Google Maps Javascript API v3?

Comment: have you said that i must include Google API on the index.html, I'm new on this thing so what can i do?

Comment: Yes. Because you have some method not included by Ext JS inside the javascript function, if you did not include google API inside index.html, the javascript can not know google variables and functions. The Ext Js only provide limited methods and view configures for google map. @FisaoranaRakotonirina

Answer (score 1):

Get a key on this site https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

After that you have to include the maps url with your like just a parameter in url key=your key in index.html
Then it will work.

The url looks like this
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap

You have to put it inside the `<script></script>` tags.